# Delphi - Get current monitor of running process's focused window (external)

Tags: delphi, screen, monitor, hwnd, window-handles

So, as mentioned in the title, I'm after identifying which monitor (in multiscreen situation) is the external process (application) running on.

I know that my form can be identified by TForm.Monitor.MonitorNum property, and so far I can get the handle of the external process by using the `FindWindowExtd` function, which I got on the net.

Later on I check if `GetForegroundWindow = FindWindowExtd('App Partial Title')`, so I only do my procedures if the external application has focus.

Since I'm doing the mouse emulator, it is vital for me to also identify the screen ID, where that application has focus.

How could I do that? The web kinda left me dry on this one too today...

Here's the code for FindWindowExtd:

```
function FindWindowExtd(partialTitle: string): HWND;
var
  hWndTemp: hWnd;
  iLenText: Integer;
  cTitletemp: array [0..254] of Char;
  sTitleTemp: string;
begin
  hWndTemp := FindWindow(nil, nil);
  while hWndTemp <> 0 do begin
    iLenText := GetWindowText(hWndTemp, cTitletemp, 255);
    sTitleTemp := cTitletemp;
    sTitleTemp := UpperCase(copy( sTitleTemp, 1, iLenText));
    partialTitle := UpperCase(partialTitle);
    if pos( partialTitle, sTitleTemp ) <> 0 then
      Break;
    hWndTemp := GetWindow(hWndTemp, GW_HWNDNEXT);
  end;
  result := hWndTemp;
end;
```

Can I use some help from the handle I get out of it?

Thanks!

Comment: See MonitorFromWindow.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Exactly what I was looking for!! Thanks for instant help!!!

Answer (score 2):

Yep!

What @Sertac Akyuz said in the comment, was what I missed and most likely didn't know how to find.

The `Screen.MonitorFromWindow(FindWindowExtd('AppPartialName')).MonitorNum` is the answer!

Thanks for quick help!